# Use RegEx or NSScanner in Obj-C to convert newline characters to html bullets

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression, nsscanner, nsformatter

My app accesses a poor web service that returns output like this:

```
Title\n\nInfo1\nInfo2\nInfo3\n ...
```

To clarify, the text is not literally `...`, and the info is not literally numbered, I just wanted to show that they are distinct.

I want to display it in a `UIWebView` like this:

```
<p><b>Title</b><ul><li>Info1</li><li>Info2</li><li>Info3</li></ul></p>
```

How can I accomplish this using either `NSRegularExpression` or `NSScanner`? I am confused about `NSRegularExpression` both because I do not know the correct expression to use, and I'm not sure how I access the results to place it in a neat formatted string.

Naively, the logic would be something like this:

1. Find all text between char 0 and first (only) occurrence of `\n\n`, and fit that into format `@"<p><b>%@</b><ul>",matchedString`
2. While there is still text, find all text between current char and next occurrence of `\n` (single) and fit into format `@"<li>%@</li>"`
3. When there are no `\n` left, append `@"</ul></p>"` and call it a day.

Please advise on how I can implement this logic, or alternatively encode it in a regular expression.

### Answer implemented

I just wanted to post my makeshift implementation of the answer in case anybody in the future get stuck:

```
NSArray *parts = [self.dogFoodBenefits componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSString *benefitsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<h4>Benefits</h4><b>%@</b><p><ul>",[parts objectAtIndex:0]];
for (int i = 2; i < [parts count]; i++) {
    if ([[parts objectAtIndex:i] length] > 1)
        benefitsString = [benefitsString stringByAppendingFormat:@"<li>%@</li>",[parts objectAtIndex:i]];
}
benefitsString = [benefitsString stringByAppendingString:@"</ul></p>"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have easier time simply splitting the string at `\n\n` using `componentsSeparatedByString:` method:

```
NSArray *parts = [webTextStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\n"];
// Use the initial or the only element inside <b></b> tag
// Put the remaining elements, if any, in the <li></li> tags
```

Comment: Would I have to use `componentsSeparatedByString` twice, once to split it into two and again to split the second part into whatever number of bullet items are there?

Comment: @jshin47 Oh, I see, the only `\n\n` there is after the initial entry. You can split on `\n` then, do it once, and ignore the empty element at position 1 (it's the empty string between the first `\n` and the second `\n`).

Comment: Ok, that's what I went ahead and did. Very cool! I wasn't aware there was something like PHP `explode` available in Objc

Answer (score 0):

you could use the method -[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:] to get what you want as an array of strings.